# How to modify class name when creating a Flutter plugin

Tags: plugins, flutter, dart, rename

I'm creating a new Flutter plugin

I named it `my_flutter_plugin` when I created it. But now I want to change the main class name.

Currently it is this:

```
// lib/my_flutter_plugin.dart

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MyFlutterPlugin {
  static const MethodChannel _channel =
      const MethodChannel('my_flutter_plugin');

  static Future<String> get platformVersion async {
    final String version = await _channel.invokeMethod('getPlatformVersion');
    return version;
  }
}
```

I'd like to change `MyFlutterPlugin` to `AnotherName`, but when I look in pubspec.dart it says:

```
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # This section identifies this Flutter project as a plugin project.
  # The androidPackage and pluginClass identifiers should not ordinarily
  # be modified. They are used by the tooling to maintain consistency when
  # adding or updating assets for this project.
  plugin:
    androidPackage: com.example.my_flutter_plugin
    pluginClass: MyFlutterPlugin
```

I want to keep the package name as `my_flutter_plugin` but this seems to indicate that I can't (or shouldn't) change the plugin class name.

How do I change the class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pluginClass` in *pubspec.yaml* is not the same as your class with the method channel. In fact, if you had named your project `my_flutter` instead of `my_flutter_plugin`, the `pluginClass` in *pubspec.yaml* would still say `myFlutterPlugin` but your lib class with the method channel would be `MyFlutter`.

### How to change the class name

In your lib folder class (in this case `lib/my_flutter_plugin.dart`), just refactor the class name as you would normally rename any class. You can rename it to `AnotherName`. As long as you are refactoring using the IDE tools, this should also update the class name in the `example` and `test` folders.

### How to change the method channel name

Just change the string name everywhere that it is used. In a new plugin project, this would be in the `lib` folder and the `test` folder. Rather than

```
static const MethodChannel _channel = 
    const MethodChannel('my_flutter_plugin');
```

You can give it a unique name like

```
static const MethodChannel _channel = 
    const MethodChannel('com.example.my_flutter_plugin/another_name');
```